# Cassandra 2.0 and later require Java 7u25 or later but i'm using jdk1.7.0_101

Tags: java-7, cassandra-2.0

I am running Cassandra Server 2.1.5. On friday, I applied the latest java 7 patch, jdk1.7.0_101. Now, cassandra will not start. The cassandra log contains, "Cassandra 2.0 and later require Java 7u25 or later."
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This should be in http://serverfault.com/

Comment: This looks like a problem with lexical comparison instead of integer comparison. The problem is in `$CASSANDRA_HOME/conf/cassandra-env.sh`.

Answer (score 2):

Open your cassandra-env.sh (/etc/dse/cassandra/cassandra-env.sh for DSE)
Comment ligne 104 (exit 1;)

`if [ "$JVM_VERSION" \< "1.8" ] && [ "$JVM_PATCH_VERSION" \< "25" ] ; then
    echo "Cassandra 2.0 and later require Java 7u25 or later."
    #exit 1;
fi`

and restart dse or cassandra.

The Problem is the comparison between the versions. In string 101 < 25.

Bye, QG

Comment: That's more a hack than a solution.